Файлы minidump в папке с проектом delphi7+oracle 11g2r
Возникла проблема с неконтролируемым созданием файлов с таким названием _minidump_default_pid_11592_tid_x4A8_2024_6_20_17_27_57.dmp. В самом проекте, написанном на delphi 7, используется библиотека ODAC для связи с Oracle. Так же сам проект является DLL, которая вызывается из приложения EXE. Из приложения передается сессия oracle (компонент OraSession из библиотеки ODAC).

Похожая проблема: https://superuser.com/questions/438315/process-keeps-creating-dump-files. И второй важный момент: между приложением и dll нельзя передавать классы, только стандартные типы Windows (даже не Delphi)! Если вы хотите передавать классы - используйте пакеты (runtime packages, *.bpl). Ну и именно для обхода этих ограничений были придуманы интерфейсы и всякие извращения, вроде COM
